# Powershell: Set-PnPListItem remove taxonomy value (empty value)[SharePoint Online]

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, taxonomy

I build a script to map some old taxonomy value from old columns to new columns and tax. values. There are some cases where I have to remove or empty current meta data. Does someone know how it works with Set-PnPListItem. While updating I pass the list item and a hash `@{field=value}`. Updating works fine but can't remove or empty.

To remove or empty I tried to set the value to `-1`, `$null` and `""` but nothing works and I will get this error: `Set-PnPListItem : Value cannot be null.`

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK5uN.png)

Comment: Isn't it a constraint of the list itself? Go to list setting check if this column require to have information

Comment: I checked but all columns in the library are not required.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test result.

```
#region Variables 
$Username = "admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" 
$Password = "Password" 
$siteURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lee"
#endregion Variables

#region Credentials 
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials

Set-PnPListItem -List "ListMetaData" -Identity 1 -Values @{"Title" = "TitleUPDATE";"MMField"=$null}
Write-Host "-----------"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]
Make sure the field is not set as required as Mike suggested.

Comment: I see. I don't get it why $null will cause into an error on my side.

Comment: Doesn't work for me too... I have a multi-value managed metadata field